# Split String after third slash

Tags: javascript, regex

Consider the following string `"/path1/path2/file.png"`.
Is it possible to extract `"/path1/path2` through an regex? If so can you provide an example and how it works for it? If not what would be the alternative?

Comment: What's the desired output ? Is it "/path1/path2" or "/file.png" ? Can you be more explicit, please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it this way:

```
var str = '/path1/path2/file.png';

var regex = /(?:\/.*\/)(.*)/;
var filename = regex.exec(str)[1];
console.log(filename);
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Ldpoqf0n/1/

this is another way without using regex:

```
var parts = str.split('/');
console.log(parts[parts.length - 1]);
```

Comment: Hehe, you're the only one who understood that needed to output the file part and not the folder path. Nice shot ! ; )

Answer (score 1):

```js
let str = '"/path1/path2/file.png"';

console.log(str.replace(/\/\w+.\w+"/, ''));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
const src = '/path1/path2/file.png'

const getFirstPart = src => (src.match(/\/.*?\/.*?(?=\/)/) || [])[0]

console.log(getFirstPart(src))
```

Answer (score 1):

With regexes:

```js
var path = "/path1/path2/file.png";
var patt = new RegExp("\/.*?\/[^\/]*");
var subpath = patt.exec(path)[0];
console.log(subpath)
```

Without regexes:

```js
function getSubpath(path, subpathLevel) {
    var arr = path.split("/");
    var subpath = "";
    for(var i = 0; i < subpathLevel && i < arr.length; i++)
        subpath += "/" + arr[i+1];
    return subpath;
}
console.log(getSubpath("/path1/path2/file.png", 2));
```

In `subpathLevel` variable you can set the quantity of slashes you want to consider (in the example is 2).